# socket.io connection not working but new Websocket working

Tags: javascript, websocket, socket.io

I' have a socket server i just try to connect that server.

when i try new Websocket my connection is works;

```
const socket = new Websocket('ws://127.0.0.1:8000');
```

but when i want to use socket.io like this;

```
const socket = io('ws://127.0.0.1:8000');
socket.on('connect', () => {
  console.log('connected');
});
```

socket io code can't connect to socket it's fired cors error everytime but new Websocket connection works easly.

I found a solution like this;

```
  socket = io('ws://127.0.0.1:8000', {
    "transports": [
      "websocket"
    ]    
  });
```

i added transports datas then socket start works.

Comment: Did you perhaps misunderstand the differences between socket.io and Websocket ? Which one are you trying to use really?

Comment: i want to use socket.io.

Comment: Then you should use socket.io instead of Websocket Web API. There are bunch of tutorials for you to understand how you can implement a socket. I am assuming that you are trying to achieve a reconnect by not initializing your socket immediately but later. So you can check out solutions like below and then please ask your question again how and where you exactly stuck. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49629881/reconnecting-a-websocket-without-creating-a-new-instance

Comment: Some tutorials : https://socket.io/get-started/chat/

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me
`socket = io('ws://localhost:8000',{transports:['websocket']});`

Thanks @Ugurcan